eliminar el espacio en blanco entre 2 section cuando la de abajo de las 2 tiene una imagen como background con un gradiente
Como elimino el espacio en blanco entre 2 section cuando la de abajo de las 2 tiene una imagen como background con un gradiente?
Ambas  no tienen padding ni margin, y ya coloqué en el CSS:
*{ box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.
Lo que sí observe es que quitando la imagen y poniendo un background-color, el espacio desaparece y quedan unidas. Debe ser una propiedad que tengo que aplicarle a ese background, pero no sé cual es.
El código del CSS de la section en cuestión es así:


.contacto {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(30, 35, 38, .8), rgba(30, 35, 38, 1)), url(img/fondoInicio.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}
<div class="contacto"></div>




te faltó agregar el código de la primera sección

Es que no tiene nada raro, por eso no crei que fuese importante, pero aca está.

acá dónde? segura que le diste click en editar a tu pregunta?

Al ejecutar tu ejemplo todo se ve bien, no luce como lo describes en la pregunta.

No tengo la solución exacta y no puedo comentar, pero en mi experiencia simplemente aumento el padding o el margin para quitar ese espacio en blanco.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
